# Custom Rest actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a friendship and I created a custom action called accept. however i can't reach it. Everytime I call it i get the action show could not be found.

Here my route.rb file

```
  resources :friendships do
    collection do
      delete 'cancel'
      get 'accept'
    end
  end
```

Here how i call it

```
<%= link_to 'Accept', accept_friendships_path(:friend_id => f) %>
```

accept_friendships was taken from rake routes commands. And here how i define my accept controller

```
  #Accept friendships
  def accept
    if @customer.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept(@customer, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship Accepted"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No Friendship request"
    end
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Here the error

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for FriendshipsController
```

Comment: Show us the actual output from the `rake routes` command as well. There's probably just a small mistmatch/typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but why you want "accept" to be a collection? I guess you want it to be a member, since you are passing friend_id. If you change it to member and make the path `accept_friendship_path(@friendship)` [ note singular form of friendship ], you might have better luck. Beside an addition argument your case does not differ from example on [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes), that is why it is worth to try it

Comment: How do i define @friendship, because there it is from an index

Comment: Never mind it worked, just had to pass f instead of @friendship thanks alot!! will check has mark in 2 min